# How to know if a user is logged into my site or not in React?

Tags: reactjs, spring

I am building a Forum-like website using React and Spring. I want the users to be able to see all the posts in the forum, but I want them to be able to comment only if they're logged in. I haven't started building the login system yet because I've been thinking about this problem for like a whole day now, so I have no code to show. So how exactly do I check if a user is logged in? Should I even be using spring security, or should I be using something else?

Comment: Either you can use cookie or state, so every request that propagates you can pass the cookie like some token and check whether its valid so in that way we can know he is logged in and the session is active

Comment: Go with JWT it's the cleanest way when it comes to managing the UI components.
https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enBG842BG842&sxsrf=ACYBGNRxEYDcKm2OZ5OER1q-rQnHxYtW7g%3A1578078774165&ei=NpIPXuPiCYuimwXfr6mwCw&q=jwt+spring&oq=jwt+spring&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67j0i203j0l8.5403.6630..8405...0.2..0.123.788.0j7......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i20i263.3W6nwS5flzw&ved=0ahUKEwjj1YvGkejmAhUL0aYKHd9XCrYQ4dUDCAs&uact=5

Answer (score 2):

Doing this really depends on what you are relying on for login and state management. Your question leaves out a key piece of information, which is what security platform are you using? Spring security, custom, something else?

Spring security can be chosen to do this. If you go that route one option is to expose an endpoint that is only allowed to authorized users that returns the Principal object back. The method looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/me")
public Principal getMe(Principal principal) {
    return principal;
}
```

You would then expose the endpoint only to authorized users like this:

```
.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/me").authenticated()
```

If the user can hit that and get a 200 back, then they are logged in. If not, they should get a 403, and you know they are not logged in.

Spring Security docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-web-security

As a more general answer only the server can determine if someone is logged in and you should not rely on any client property to determine this. All client code should be considered compromised, so you will need a way to talk to the server to make this determination.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used Spring but generally on the client side you would set some state variable when the server acknowledges the user's credentials and only show the comment field if it is set. Of course, the client has control over his/her browser, so you should also check server side when a comment is submitted whether the user is authenticated or not.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read [This](https://auth0.com/docs/flows) doc and it will help you know the most famous authentication flows.

After you select a flow for implementing you have to search for it and find a proper way for doing it, If you have any questions, we are here to help you